# How come std::array be stored on the stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I learned about the stack and the heap recently, and something doesn't make sense.

I read that std::array is stored on the stack even though the count and size of the elements of the size is unknown.

the same way you can't read input of unknown length to the stack from the user.

what am I missing here?

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from reading input into variables that are stack allocated.  The main reason against this is that the size of the stack is usually smaller than the heap or other memory areas.  For example, you can read small blocks (objects) into a stack variable; many times, there is no reason to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: Also, `std::array` can be created in heap memory, it doesn't HAVE to reside in stack memory. It would be more accurate to say that `std::array` is *typically* created in **automatic** memory (which can be on either the stack or the heap, depending on context) or in **dynamic** memory (which is typically on the heap).  The stack and heap are just *implementation details* based on the target system. Instead, think of memory usage in terms of *automatic*, *dynamic*, *static*, etc. That is how the C++ standard refers to them.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time. I understand now.

Answer (score 5):

To create an `std::array` you have to specify in its template ([or let the compiler deduce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides))  both the count and the type of the elements stored. That makes the size known at compile time, hence it can be instantiated on the stack.

`std::array` is nothing but a thin wrapper around C-style arrays. The size is fixed, it cannot grow nor shrink.